# UIAlertController accepts text input, set cell label to text input

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to have a UIAlertController accept text from the user and set the user's input as the label of the first cell of the table view.

```
var objects = [AnyObject]()

func insertNewObject(sender: AnyObject) {

    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Routine", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    var inputTextField: UITextField?

    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({(textField: UITextField!) in
        textField.placeholder = "Routine Name"
        inputTextField = textField
    })
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        self.objects.insert(inputTextField!, atIndex: 0)
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
        self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Unfortunately, this sets the cell label to something like <_UIAlertControllerTextField:...

I am guessing it is in the action of the "Add" button I have with "inputTextField". I am unsure of how to correctly capture the text submitted by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the text field to your array when you should be adding its contents.

Instead of:

```
self.objects.insert(inputTextField!, atIndex: 0)
```

do this:

```
self.objects.insert(inputTextField.text!, atIndex: 0)
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. A very dumb mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

U can used the [String] array for the TableView text to show . 
In the alertAddAction, U can capture the text like this:

```
var objects = [String]()

func insertNewObject(sender: AnyObject) {

var alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Routine", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
// var inputTextField: UITextField? // No need for this 

alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({(textField: UITextField!) in
    textField.placeholder = "Routine Name"
    //inputTextField = textField
})
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

    if let textFields = alert.textFields{
        let theTextFields = textFields as! [UITextField]  // used this to capture the text 
        let object = theTextFields[0].text
        self.objects.insert(object, atIndex: 0)
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
        self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    }
}))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}

U can try and see it can work for U.